# vba - worksheet references in formula

Tags: excel, vba, reference, worksheet-function, worksheet

I can't figure it out. I'm trying to make my formular more dynamic. But it always **says prev can not be found**, but I set prev as a worksheet.
PrevSheetName gives back the name of the previous worksheet (that works).
Please help me, in my other code I always tried to use "ActiveSheet.Previous" but it seems not to work with formulas.

```
Set prev = Worksheets(PrevSheetName)
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("D3")
rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(prev!C[1],RC[-2],prev!C[5])"
Range("D3").Copy Range("D4:D" & lRow)
```

This is my first code and that works

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("D3")
rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF('Projekt 1'!C[1],RC[-2],'Projekt 1'!C[5])"
Range("D3").Copy Range("D4:D" & lRow)
```

and this is my PrevSheetName, is already puts the name in `" "`

```
Function PrevSheetName(Optional ByVal WS As Worksheet = Nothing) As String
    Application.Volatile True
    Dim S As String
    Dim Q As String
    If IsObject(Application.Caller) = True Then
        Set WS = Application.Caller.Worksheet
        If WS.Index = 1 Then
            With Application.Caller.Worksheet.Parent.Worksheets
                Set WS = .Item(.Count)
            End With
        Else
           Set WS = WS.Previous
        End If
        If InStr(1, WS.Name, " ", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            Q = "'"
        Else
            Q = vbNullString
        End If
    Else
        If WS Is Nothing Then
            Set WS = ActiveSheet
        End If
        If WS.Index = 1 Then
            With WS.Parent.Worksheets
                Set WS = .Item(.Count)
            End With
        Else
            Set WS = WS.Previous
        End If
        Q = vbNullString
    End If
    PrevSheetName = Q & WS.Name & Q
End Function
```

I just want to exchange 'Projekt 1' with the previous sheet

Comment: as i see it, you use "prev" as part of a formular like you would type it in the excel sheet and not as VBA variable.
try this:
replace `"=SUMIF(prev!C[1],RC[-2],prev!C[5])"` with `"=SUMIF(" & prev.name & "!C[1],RC[-2]," & prev.name & "!C[5])"`

the process you're doing in vba is the same like typing the formular into the excel cell by hand. This means the worksheet's name has to be part of your cell value and not the variable name.

Comment: thanks, but how do i fix it?

Comment: i submitted my comment to early ;-) it's fixed now

Comment: try to get this formula by hand in the excel sheet once and then rebuild it using vba. Use the watches-object in order to find the correct value of the prev-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sheet name has spaces as well as concatention you will need to add ' around the name in the formula like this "=SUMIF('" & PrevSheetName & "'!C[1],RC[-2],'" & PrevSheetName & "'!C[5])"

Answer (score 0):

prev is a literal part of the formula. It is looking for sheet called "prev". You need to concatenate formula: `"=SUMIF(" & PrevSheetName & "!C[1],RC[-2]," & PrevSheetName & "!C[5])"`

Comment: You actually need `prev.Name` and in both parts of the formula.

Comment: PrevSheetName gives me back a string (ex. "sheet1")

Comment: mhh, it still doesnt. the formula still searches for a worksheet calles PrevSheetName and not the name this function returns

Comment: @Anneh, are you sure you enter the formula as is provided? On the first llok, it have to work as well.